# How to fix Qt5 unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, 16.10, qt, qt5

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 with Qt4.8.7 and I'd like to install Qt5 in order to compile a package. I installed `qt5-qmake` from the repo, and set the default to qt5:

```
export QT_SELECT=qt5
./configure && make
...fatal error: QtCore/QTextCodec: No such file or directory
```

So the package wouldn't compile, apparently because of an include statement:

```
include "<"QtCore/QtGlobal
```

for which I think I need the development environment. First, I tried to install it from the Qt site, by downloading qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.1.run, then I tried to install `qtbase5-dev` from Synaptic.

That didn't work because of unmet dependencies. All the installed files mentioned are ubuntu7-2 versions from  the main Ubuntu Yakkety repo; the required ubuntu6-4 versions are also available. They are also used in a great many other packages which I can't afford to break.

```
$ sudo aptitude install qtbase5-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed: libegl1-mesa-dev{a} libgles2-mesa-dev{a} libglu1-mesa-dev{a} libmirclient-dev{ab} libmircommon-dev{ab} libmircookie-dev{ab} libprotobuf-dev{a} libqt5opengl5-dev{ab} libwayland-bin{a} libwayland-dev{a} libxkbcommon-dev{a} qt5-qmake{a} qtbase5-dev{b} qtbase5-dev-tools{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,473 kB of archives. After unpacking 33.6 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5opengl5-dev : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
 libmirclient-dev : Depends: libmirclient9 (= 0.24.0+16.10.20160815.3-0ubuntu2) but 0.24.1+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libmircommon-dev : Depends: libmircommon6 (= 0.24.0+16.10.20160815.3-0ubuntu2) but 0.24.1+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is installed
 qtbase5-dev : Depends: libqt5concurrent5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5core5a (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5dbus5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5network5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5sql5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5test5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5widgets5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
               Depends: libqt5xml5 (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4) but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 is installed
 libmircookie-dev : Depends: libmircookie2 (= 0.24.0+16.10.20160815.3-0ubuntu2) but 0.24.1+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
         Keep the following packages at their current version:     1)     libegl1-mesa-dev [Not Installed]                        2)     libgles2-mesa-dev [Not Installed]                  
3)     libmirclient-dev [Not Installed]                   
4)     libmircommon-dev [Not Installed]                   
5)     libmircookie-dev [Not Installed]                   
6)     libqt5opengl5-dev [Not Installed]                  
7)     qtbase5-dev [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] ?
```

Apt-get's solution is to leave it unchanged.

It seems odd that the main repo version of Qt 5.6.1 requires different libraries to the other packages.

It looks like I need to downgrade these libraries from 7.2 to to 6.4. Can I do this safely, and install Qt 5.6.1? Or is there a better way to fix the problem?

```
$ apt-cache policy libqt5core5a
libqt5core5a:
  Installed: 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2
  Candidate: 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2
  Version table:
 *** 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu7~2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4 500
        500 http://mirrors.psu.ac.th/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
```

I eventually sorted this out by using Synaptic to force the qtbase5-dev dependencies to the previous (Yakkety-upgrades or Yakkety) versions.

This left the libmir files. Manually installing them failed, but shows the problematic dependencies. Repeating for the dependencies and working down through them eventually led to one or two files which needed to be downgraded.

Forcing that via Synaptic also removed a host of basic Yakkety applications; it's a pity I couldn't find a way to downgrade them in parallel, keeping a consistent system, but in the end I let them go, installed Qt5, and manually reinstalled the missing packages by using Synaptic's Status 'Not installed (residual config)' section to identify and reinstall them.

I had a couple of minor issues with security-related packages on reboot, but quickly solved with Google.

Comment: There are pending package upgrades available that conflict with the package installation. Please try `sudo apt-get upgrade qtbase5-dev`.

Comment: That lists the same unmet dependencies. Which versions of the libraries are other people using?

Comment: Odd. Then could you please try `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev`?

Comment: Similar with the omission of three items:

               Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                        libglu-dev
               Depends: qt5-qmake (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4)
               Depends: qtbase5-dev-tools (= 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu6~4)

Is everyone else on 6.4 or 7.2 versions of these libraries?

Sorry I can't get paragraphs into this today

Comment: Is that output of `upgrade` or `install`? Which packages were upgraded during `upgrade`?

Comment: No packages were upgraded or installed: "The following packages have been kept back:
digikam5 digikam5-data linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-signed-generic linux-signed-image-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 7 not to upgrade."

Comment: That's odd. What's the output of `apt-cache policy libqt5core5a`?

Comment: OK I think I may have figured out the cause. When I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 (downloaded by torrent) some of the config files were for 17.04 Zesty including repos. It looks like I've got at least one Ubuntu7 version in there, which may be preventing the downgrade.

Comment: I looked at /var/lib/dpkg/status and noticed at least one package xorg-xserver-core which is from the Zesty repo. This doesn't seem to be preventing the up/downgrade though.

Comment: I can't be bothered to read that garbled output listing. Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: To [edit] your question click the link in this comment or the "edit" link below the question. If you don't see [an editor like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdQiM.png) (except the colour scheme) please [open a question on Meta.AskUbuntu](//meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask) which is dedicated to question *about* AskUbuntu.